# How to add an image to all pages in an Rmarkdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, officedown

I would like to add an image to every page of my Rmarkdown file in docx format, which represents my header and footer.

My yaml is:

```
---
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Ecovery - Soluções Ambientais"
title: "Plano Operacional Anual - 2022"
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: "template.docx"
    tables:
      style: 'Tab_Ecovery'
  
---
```

This would be the image you would like to add, on the edges of the pages (in A4 format):

[image]

Comment: I managed to add the header and footer through the template with the latest version of officedown:
https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/350